# Sapling Tree Gen Add-On doesn't work how I want it

Tags: sapling-addon

I am a noob at Blender and I wanted to make a plant for my Roblox game. I looked at Youtube for tutorials and this one person said I should use the *Sapling Tree Gen* add-on. So I installed it. But whenever I hit *Quaking Aspen* in the presets tab, like the person in the video said, the tree becomes really thin like one edge?

Can somebody help?

[image]

Comment: Please add your image directly into your question rather than expecting us to copy and visit external links! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.  That addon setting works fine for me so it might help if you added an image of your Blender screen which you can produce via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu. It would also help if we could see your Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.